# Decreasing one cell based on the amount placed in another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

In a budget you have a total number of payments. Let's say your payment is $100. for every $100 you spend your monthly payment will decrease by 1. If Cell one has my payment amount and cell 2 has the number of payments.

How can I make my number of payments decrease based on the amount spent?

```
Cell 1              Cell 2
$100                  23 Payments
```

I want it to calculate the number of payments I have left.

Comment: Since you have a cell containing "23 Payments", it's difficult to do calculations using just the 23 portion of it.  Suggest you make the column heading "Payments Remaining" or put the word Payments in the next column.  Then Cell 2 contains just 23, and you can put "=C2-1" in the next cell down or wherever the updated number of payments will be.

Answer (score 0):

So we start off with your total initial number of payments. Let's say 60. Then for every $100 we spend, we knock off one payment. Let's put our payment amounts into cell A2.

```
=60-A2/100
```

Now let's pretend that sometimes you'll make a partial payment, but you don't want it to decrease the number of payments total. For example, if you've spent $150, you only want it to decrease by one payment. Same if you've spent $199, you want 59 payments to show up. We get:

```
=60-Floor(A2/100)
```

If we want to round it, so $110 gets 59, and $190 gets 58, we get

```
=60-Round(A2/100,0)
```

Tada!